# Notepad++ customize any word's color

Tags: notepad++

for example, after setting

typedef unsigned int uint

I want uint to be purple. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you search the web for how to customize Notepad++' syntax highlighting? Did you try any of the existing possibilities? If so (twice), hiw did it fail?

Comment: @RadLexus All I could find is a standard language style setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it "manually": open **Settings->Style Configurator** and select your (current) programming language (I suppose it is C for your example).
Into **Style** tab, select **TYPE WORD** and add (for this case) *uint* in the **User-defined keywords** box